# How to plot graph in excel for date and time as two data columns

Tags: excel, graph, charts

I am struggling to plot graph using date and time columns. My excel is as below:

[image]

Help me plot graph for this data. Thanks.

Comment: Dates into X axis and times into Y axis?

Comment: Yes, dates on X and time on Y

Comment: What are yoy tring to plot? When doing a graph it's because you want to show/see something. What in your case? Also, notice there are duplicates in your values and probably they should be sorted

Comment: I want to plot date against time to show how long the vehicle has waited per day due to halt.

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns thats not duplicated, they are. different vehciles.

Comment: Lets say we have vehcile name, date , time, have to plot how long the vehicle has waited in each dates

Comment: There is no vehicle name in your data so rows 3 and 4 got the same info. Please, add the vehicle name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244396/discussion-between-lote-marsk-chozey-and-foxfire-and-burns-and-burns).

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you want each vehicle to be its own series.
with the time plotted for each on a specific date.
the only way I see to plot the data is as follows...

[image]